# date picker overlaping with datatable contents in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image]Good day guys..
I implemented a component datepicker in angular and but I am having problems with the bootstrap datatable library that it's part of the project, and I have this bad UX Experience error (see structure for the component and image below)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Select a date</mat-label>
              
                <input matInput 
                    [matDatepicker]="dp"  
                    
                    [min]="minDate1" 
                    [max]="maxDate1"   
                    [value]="initialDate"
                    (dateInput)="dateChanged($event)" 
                    (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)"
                    disabled
                >
         ....
```

[image]

I want to customize the component and avoid show this borders in the component with CSS

::ng-deep

```
  .mat-calendar  {
    border: none;
    display: none; 
    
    }
```

But I can find the right way.

I am using indigo theme

can you help me please.

thank you.

Comment: Please add an image where you highlight the borders you want to hide. Also, a stackblitz instance of your scenario would be useful.

Comment: Which bootstrap datatable library are you using?